# Morris Chart hover point size

Tags: javascript, morris.js

using morris chart

options

```
Morris.Line({
            element: 'Chart',
            data: $scope.chartModel,
            xkey: $scope.xkey,
            ykeys: $scope.ykeys,
            labels: ['Success Percent'],
            pointFillColors: ['#BF4040'],
            pointSize: '7',
            hideHover: 'always'

        }).on('click', function (i, row) { // Not running code }
```

Problem:I made the point size of 7.But when it comes to size 73 going on.Click event does not work when it comes off the event on.How do I adjust the size that comes on the point ?

Chart: [You can view it here](http://jsbin.com/yuqamuciva/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes from around your `pointSize`.  This value should be an integer, not a string.  Also, the `hideHover` option will disable hover effects, so remove it if you would like the points to change size on hover.

```
Morris.Line({
    element: 'Chart',
    data: $scope.chartModel,
    xkey: $scope.xkey,
    ykeys: $scope.ykeys,
    labels: ['Success Percent'],
    pointFillColors: ['#BF4040'],
    pointSize: 7
}).on('click', function (i, row) { /* Not running code */ });
```

As for your click event not working, you are using version 0.4.1 of Morris.js.  [Version 0.4.2](https://github.com/morrisjs/morris.js/releases/tag/0.4.2) added support for click events.

See [this JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/jaduramogi/1/edit?html,js,console,output) to see these changes in action.  It uses the latest version of Morris.js.